# Save css files using Notepad as Encoding of Ansi or UTF-8?

Tags: css

I'm new at web development and css, 
One simple question came into my mind...
I know how to create a css file, but I'm not sure save this Encoding file as ANSI or UTF-8 when I save the file using Notepad? 
I'm not sure which one is the best choice.
I searched on the internet, but I didn't find something helpful.
I want to know which one is the best choice for saving the file as css that will not be a problem in the future.
Please take a look at the attach image
Thanks for your helps.
[Aattch01, when save a file using windows Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIViq.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you save in UTF8
pos if in a futuri your css has characters like 
áéíóúñäëïöü, and others more than ANSI would only show an error.

A site where you can find those characters for example is in a content of a pseudelement like:

```
.menu .spain:after{
    content:"España";
}
```

result UTF8:   "España"
result ANSI:   "Espa[]a"

Also recommend you to use an editor that gives you more comforts like Atom, which is very simple to use.
Although you may be afraid of it, is a simple editor with many aids to program